# make multiple ajax execute in order

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The problem here is since the success function will lead the page to another php page. Then the rest of the ajax code will not be executed anymore.
Wondering how to make the rest of the code still can be executed after first success function is finished.

```
$.ajax({
            context:$this,
            url:"/yyqGS/public/form/get_clicked_index.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{index:'-1' ,index2:$cid},
            success:function () {


            $this.parent().attr("action","/yyqGS/public/form/reply.php?c_id=" + $cid);
                $this.parent().submit();


                $.ajax({
                    url:"/yyqGS/public/form/get_url.php",
                    type:"GET",
                    success:function (d1) {

                        var $data = d1.split(",");
                        location.href = "/yyqGS/public/form/reply_notification2.php?id="+$data[0]+"&country="+$data[1]+"&tid="+$data[2]+"&cid="+$data[3]+"&rid="+$data[4]+"&cuser="+$data[5];

                    },
                    fail:function () {
                        alert("f");
                    }
                })
            }
        })
```

Comment: why do you submit the form then anyway if you wanna stay there and do something else, that leads you to another redirect?

Comment: put the form-submit in another ajax call and put the rest (the 3rd ajax...) in that success callback

Comment: @Jeff sorry, but i don't really understand, how do i do that?

Comment: This process flow doesn't make any sense. To be honest I don't see why you use ajax at all for this

Comment: @charlietfl actually i just realized i can just combine tow php into one, i don't really need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a try with Deferred Object https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/